# My page appears differently in IE 10 than in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: html, internet-explorer-10

I am fairly new to HTML5 so please bear with me.  I have designed a site for someone and when I view it in Firefox or Chrome, all is well, but when I view it in Internet Explorer 10, the nav menu and the picture in the header are moved downward. I have checked the site at http://validator.w3.org/ and it gave me some errors like alt is missing and some other minor things which I believe are irrelevant to what is causing this problem. Is there a way for me to override this with some type of Javascript code or is there some way of just making an IE 10 friendly version of the page in which someone who puts in the url of the page will be redirected to the IE version of the page?

Here is the url of the site: daxxomatic.com

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to web programming and comparability issues. Internet explorer is the largest used web browser and the most horrific browser for web programmers.

You have to live with it and do one of the hacks for dealing with the problem. I would suggest that you follow web standards and check out www.caniuse.com to see if what you are doing can work on IE or Firefox or whatever.

Lastly, test your code in different browsers as you develop a project. That way you deal with small chunks of problems than a big one at the end.

Comment: I figured out what was happening. It seems like IE 10 has a problem with div tags for some reason or another. Although the div tag that I have for my picture works in Firefox and Chrome, for some reason it did not work in IE 10 which caused the picture to move down automatically. The css and code for the picture are correct but IE 10 or does not recognize this. I removed the div tag from the picture and that is what solved the problem.